# Display two fields side by side in a Bootstrap Form

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to display a year range input on a form that has a 2 textboxes. One for the min and one for the max and are separated by a dash.

I want this all on the same line using bootstrap, but I cannot seem to get it to work correctly.

Here's my code:

```
<form id="Form1" class="form-horizontal" role="form" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tbxContactPhone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Year</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" MaxLength="4" />
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">-</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" MaxLength="4" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's what it looks like now:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 165, accepted):

How about using an [input group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) to style it on the same line?

**Here's the final HTML to use**:

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="End"/>
</div>
```

**Which will look like this**:

[image: screenshot]

**Here's a Stack Snippet Demo**:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="End"/>
</div>
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to translate it into an `asp:textbox` element

Comment: Problem is as soon as you remove the addon, the lines will be broken. If I set the `span`'s visibility to `hidden` it still leaves the gap on, setting its `width` doesn't help much.

Comment: @Shimmy, well of course breaking bootstrap intend HTML structure is going to break the formatting.  That's not really so much a *problem*  with this solution, but a brand new use case.  OP had a hyphen so I included one as well. Depending on what you're trying to do, you could remove the hyphen and replace with `&nbsp` and set the span's padding to `1px`.  Or you could put each input into a `.col-xs-6` container in order to place two side by side.  But I wouldn't call the current solution "problematic"

Comment: if i remove `<span class="input-group-addon">-</span>` then the line coming in next line. any solution.?

Answer (score 11):

@KyleMit's answer on Bootstrap 4 has changed a little

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">-</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `.form-control` class renders like a `DIV` element which according to the `normal-flow-of-the-page` renders on a new line.

One way of fixing issues like this is to use `display:inline` property. So, create a custom `CSS` class with `display:inline` and attach it to your component with a `.form-control` class. You have to have a `width` for your component as well.

There are other ways of handling this issue (like arranging your `form-control` components inside any of the `.col` classes), but the easiest way is to just make your `.form-control` an `inline` element (the way a `span` would render)

Answer (score 3):

### Bootstrap 3.3.7:

Use `form-inline`.

It only works on screen resolutions greater than 768px though. To test the snippet below make sure to click the "Expand snippet" link to get a wider viewing area.

```html
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <form class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>-<input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </form>
```

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline

Answer (score 3):

For Bootstrap 4

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start"/>
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="">-</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="End"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

did you check boostrap website? search for "forms"

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="col">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
</div>
<div class="col">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@KyleMit answer is one way to  solve this, however we may chose to avoid the undivided input fields acheived by `input-group` class. A better way to do this is by using `form-group` and `row` classes on a parent `div` and use `input` elements with grid-system classes provided by bootstrap.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <input class="form-control col-md-6" type="text">
    <input class="form-control col-md-6" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put two inputs inside a div with class `form-group` and set display flex on the div style

```
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group" style="display: flex;"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Nome e sobrenome" style="margin-right: 4px;" /><input type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-left: 4px;" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" /></div>
<div class="form-group" style="display: flex;"><input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" style="margin-right: 4px;" /><input type="tel" class="form-control" style="margin-left: 4px;" name="telephone" placeholder="Telefone" /></div>
<div class="form-group"><input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" /></div>
<div class="form-group"><input type="password" class="form-control" name="password-repeat" placeholder="Password (repeat)" /></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check"><label class="form-check-label"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" />I agree to the license terms.</label></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button></div><a class="already" href="#">You already have an account? Login here.</a></form>
```